# Moved database dir | Can't acess mysql through default port 3306 from localhost or poller

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rrd, cacti

WORK: The only way I can localy acess is to specify the locaction dir of the database in DATABASE_PORT ex:

```
$database_type     = 'mysql';
$database_default  = 'database';
$database_hostname = 'localhost';
$database_username = 'cacti';
$database_password = 'password';
$database_port     = 'common/mysql/mysql.socket';
$database_retries  = 5;
$database_ssl      = false;
$database_ssl_key  = '';
$database_ssl_cert = '';
$database_ssl_ca   = '';
```

DOES NOT WORK: Cacti is trying to connect the database but it can't reach like this:

```
$database_type     = 'mysql';
$database_default  = 'database';
$database_hostname = 'localhost';
$database_username = 'cacti';
$database_password = 'password';
**$database_port     = '3306';**
$database_retries  = 5;
$database_ssl      = false;
$database_ssl_key  = '';
$database_ssl_cert = '';
$database_ssl_ca   = '';
```

NOT WORKING: Remote Poller

```
$rdatabase_type     = 'mysql';
$rdatabase_default  = 'database_main';
$rdatabase_hostname = 'remote_host';
$rdatabase_username = 'cacti';
$rdatabase_password = 'password';
$rdatabase_port     = '3306'
$rdatabase_retries  = 5;
$rdatabase_ssl      = false;
```

How I moved the database:

First check  the default dir:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@datadir;

Output
+-----------------+
| @@datadir       |
+-----------------+
| /var/lib/mysql/ |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec
```

Stoped process:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
```

Rsynk the default database dir to the new location

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /common/
```

Rename old mysql

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak
```

Edit my.conf fie:

```
    sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
    [mysqld]
    . . .
    datadir=/common/mysql
    socket=/common/mysql/mysql.sock
    . . .
```

start mysql:

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

New location  datadir;

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@datadir;
+----------------+
| @@datadir      |
+----------------+
| /common/mysql/ |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'
    -> ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

my.conf

[client-server]
port=3306